# My database don't wanna display all I want

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make a page for seeing the ads of an user with around 5 ads and just 1 is displayed, here's the code :

```
<?php
try
{
$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '', $pdo_options);
$r = $db->query('SELECT id, inputid FROM ads WHERE inputid='.$_SESSION['log'].'');
echo '<ol>';
while($data = $r->fetch())
{
echo '<li><a href="adpage.php?id='.$data['id'].'">'.$adpage.'</a></li>';
$r->closeCursor();
}
echo '</ol>';
?>
```

thanks for helps

Answer (score 5):

```
while($data = $r->fetch())
{
echo '<li><a href="adpage.php?id='.$data['id'].'">'.$adpage.'</a></li>';
$r->closeCursor();   //<-- put this out of the loop
}
```

Like this

```
while($data = $r->fetch())
{
echo '<li><a href="adpage.php?id='.$data['id'].'">'.$adpage.'</a></li>';
}

$r->closeCursor();
```